# Storing list of LatLng values to a bundle

Tags: android

I have a list of LatLng values stored being populated overtime and stored within a fragment:

```
List<LatLng> mMapList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

However when the user changes orientation these values or wiped, now I'm attempting to store the ArrayList in a bundle and retrieve it that way, is this possible? Can't seem to get it to store an ArrayList of type LatLng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `LatLng` implements `Parcelable`, [`putParcelableArrayList()` should work](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29).

Comment: Tried that, but it throws the error that Parcelable cannot be applied to LatLng.

Comment: @JohnMcElreavey: Post your code where you are calling `putParcelableArrayList()`. `LatLng` implements `Parcelable` according to its JavaDocs.

Comment: Sorry you're right actually if you look at the snippet of code I posted I was setting mMapList to be a List instead of an ArrayList, seems to do the trick now that I've changed it. Thanks

Comment: @JohnMcElreavey: I am surprised that you got that specific compiler error, but I am glad to hear that it is now working.

Comment: Hmm for some reason I can get it as a ParcelableArrayList fine, but when I try to bring it back it's saying "incompatible types: ArrayList<Parcelable> cannot be converted to ArrayList<LatLng>"

EDIT:
Duh, I just changed it to <LatLng>getParcelableArrayList and alls good.